# on css overriding fail even full path css (Primefaces)

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to override background of PF slider with following codes

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"
      href="#{request.contextPath}/images/favicon.ico" />
   <title></title>

</h:head>
<body>
    <f:facet name="last">
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css.css" />
   </f:facet>
```

relevant part of css.css

```
.usagePanels.myslider.ui-widget-content,
html body div form#formData div#sliderDIV.ui-panel div#sliderDIV_content.ui-panel-content table tbody tr td table tbody tr td div#wwwpanel.ui-panel div#wwwpanel_content.ui-panel-content table#j_idt29.ui-panelgrid tbody tr.ui-widget-content td div#j_idt31.myslider
{
background-color: black!important;
}
```

It produces following html, but slider background is not black.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/DataUsageCalculator/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-blitzer" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/DataUsageCalculator/faces/javax.faces.resource/css.css?ln=css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/DataUsageCalculator/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css?ln=primefaces" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DataUsageCalculator/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DataUsageCalculator/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces"></script>
```

when I inspect applied styles on sliders and disable line

.ui-widget-content {
    ***background: url("/DataUsageCalculator/faces/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png?ln=primefaces-blitzer") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #FFFFFF;***

}

with firebug it works. 
Even I use full path css it does not work normally.
What am I doing wrong?

Applied Styles (Firebug output)

```
element.style {
    width: 300px;
}
.usagePanels.myslider.ui-widget-content, html body div form#formData div#sliderDIV.ui-panel div#sliderDIV_content.ui-panel-content table tbody tr td table tbody tr td div#wwwpanel.ui-panel div#wwwpanel_content.ui-panel-content table#j_idt29.ui-panelgrid tbody tr.ui-widget-content td div#j_idt31.myslider {
    background-color: black !important;
}
.usagePanels .ui-widget-content {
    background-color: #F5FAFF !important;
}
.sliderDIV .ui-widget-content {
}
.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal {
    height: 0.8em;
}
.ui-slider {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
.ui-corner-all {
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    background: url("/DataUsageCalculator/faces/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png?ln=primefaces-blitzer") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    color: #333333;
}
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    color: #333333;
}
.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-panelgrid {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    color: #333333;
}
.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    color: #333333;
}
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    color: #333333;
}
.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    color: #333333;
}
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
element.style {
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Sans","Verdana,Arial,sans serif";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong.

```
<h:head>
    ...
<h:head>
<body>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css.css" />
    </f:facet>
    ...
</body>
```

The `<body>` is not a JSF component and the PrimeFaces-specific `<f:facet name="last">` should go inside the `<h:head>`.

You should use either

```
<h:head>
    ...
    <f:facet name="last">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css.css" />
    </f:facet>
<h:head>
<h:body>
    ...
</h:body>
```

or

```
<h:head>
    ...
<h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css.css" />
    ...
</h:body>
```

in order to get it to load after PrimeFaces' one.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you're not using the `library` attribute the right way. Please carefully read [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used) and cleanup your wrong resource library approach.

Comment: I had already tried that too. No change. And also I read that page too http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-override-primefaces-css/. he says contrary. May be I am misunderstanding. Anyway, none of two cases worked. Because my css is loaded after theme.css, before primefaces.css. Style in theme.css (comes from  primefaces theme), ui-widget-content can not overwritten.

Comment: Sorry, works just fine for me: http://www.screencast.com/t/7lbvZl8Gfo Your problem is caused elsewhere than in the information provided so far. Perhaps your CSS selector is just wrong. The `.usagePanels` looks suspicious.

Comment: I posted a comment at that mkyong article.

Comment: You deserve the biggest thanks as usual. I will check everything from the beginning. I would like to read your comment about mkyong article, however I could not find it.