# Primefaces f:facet name="first" and "last" in h:head not used for the order

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I wanted to override the appearance of `.ui-menubar` - however, anything I put in my default.css is not taking because it is overriden by the Primefaces components.css that somehow comes after it.

I have attempted to change the order by using facets as follows:

```
<h:head>
  <f:facet name="first">
    <title>Report Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11; IE=10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="last">
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/default.css"/>
  </f:facet>
</h:head>
```

Note that this  section is part of a template.

Which renders as follows:

```
<head id="j_idt2">
  <title>Report Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11; IE=10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/my-web/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-redmond">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/my-web/javax.faces.resource/css/default.css.xhtml">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/my-web/javax.faces.resource/components.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.2">
  [javascript resources omitted for brevity ...]
</head>
```

I was using the latest Primefaces which is at time of writing 6.2.

The rendered output, clearly shows `components.css` after my custom `default.css`.

How can this be correctly ordered?

Note that I can override the style correctly if I avoid using `<h:outputStylesheet>`, example as follows:

```
  <f:facet name="last">
    <style>
      .ui-menubar  {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </f:facet>
```

That is my workaround, but I consider that not a proper design by hardcoding this in my page, rather than a css.

Note that there are several other similar postings, but I need to emphasize that I *DO* use and want to use the proper ordering of `<h:outputStylesheet>` output, and not some other workaround using inline styles etc. Also I am not yet able to find a duplicate posting with a working answer, although I am continuing to research.

Also note that [PrimeFaces documents](https://www.primefaces.org/resource-rendering/) the use of `<f:facets>` within the `<h:head>` tag very clearly:

> PrimeFaces has it’s own HeadRenderer implementing the following order:
>
> - “first” facet if defined
> - Theme CSS
> - “middle” facet if defined
> - PF-JSF registered CSS and JS
> - Head content
> - “last” facet if defined

This means the last facet *after anything else*.

Comment: 1: PF version, 2: where does your index.css end-up? 3: what is the more omitted? 4: what if you put the last facet before the first?

Comment: Updated info in original posting - and for (4./) changing the order of the facets changes exactly nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was downvoted, I was interested in the same, as a workaround we are using `!importatnt` in our CSS files, but only because I found nothing better so far...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles

Comment: Yep move your `<f:facet name="last">` to the `<h:body>` section and get it out of `<h:head>`

Comment: Reference: https://www.primefaces.org/resource-rendering/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251019/jsf-ffacet-contents-not-rendered and https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/resource-ordering-in-primefaces/ @JasperdeVries: Related link indeed, specificicalle the checking for additional headrenderers (like e.g. omnifaces?)

Comment: Well not as per [Official Primefaces documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/resource-rendering/) - see updated Posting and provided link - carefully note the use of `<f:facet>` inside `<h:head>` - using it outside might be an unintended side effect.

Comment: A post on a website is not the officical documentation for a version... It is merely a reference it at least once worked. It is nowhere in the recent 6.2 docs. But the code is still there: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/renderkit/HeadRenderer.java and read _"You'll probably also see suggestions to put it in <f:facet name="last"> of <h:head> which is understood by PrimeFaces-specific HeadRenderer, but this is unnecessarily clumsy and would break when you have your own (*read* or other) HeadRenderer."_ in the link by @JasperdeVries

Comment: So please set a breakpoint in it and debug...

Comment: Right - also I saw several postings by @BalusC suggesting that `<f:facet name="last">` in `<h:body>` is wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13917850/157882 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8774997/157882 and him repeating that on a comment on https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-override-primefaces-css/ - I suspect something else is going wrong with the HeaderRender, like what happens if I include both Omnifaces and Primefaces in my project ... Omnifaces also has its own HeaderRender, and has a different approach - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51073284/744133

Comment: I have over 25 PrimeFaces + OmniFaces projects and put the CSS in the `<h:body/>` and it always properly comes after the PF CSS

Comment: OmniFaces has no custom HeadRenderer at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I put the `<facet name="last"` inside the body and it worked.